# $\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2}\delta(x^3)dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

How to solve

$$\int_{-1}^{1}x^{2}\delta(x^3)dx$$

where $\delta(x)$ is dirac delta.

I tried a substitution $$y=x^3$$$$\frac{1}{3x^2}dy=dx$$

$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{3}\delta(y)dy=\frac{1}{3}$$

But I know the result is wrong. How am I wrong?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your approach is the heuristic way of arriving at the correct result.  Well done!

Comment: I put it on Matemathica and it gave me $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\vartheta (x)$ I can't understand why this result.

Comment: Why would the result depend on a spurious parameter $t$???

Comment: I'm so sorry I made a mistake.

Comment: The same holds for $x$ (which is a dummy = integration variable).

Comment: I put it on Matemathica and it gave me $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\vartheta (0)$ I can't understand why this result.

Comment: I guess $\theta$ is the step function? The step function is undefined for $x=0$, so the result given by Mathematica is undefined. This is clearly wrong. I don't think it is useful to understand why Mathematica produces wrong results. It is much more useful to being able to derive the correct results as you have shown. By the way:  if you defined $\theta(0)=1/2$, the result would be fine.

Comment: @Fabian $\texttt{Mathematica}$ defines $\Theta:  \mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{0\right\} \to \mathbb{R}$. However, it yields results which involve $\Theta\left(0\right)$. It's annoying !!!.

Comment: Mathematica is decidedly not great for many kinds of integrals. This is one such integral.

Comment: @Dr.MV I guess it must be a $Principal\ Value$ to avoid the nasty $x^{2}$-feature in the denominator. In that case the integral $\color{#f00}{vanishes\ out}$. What do you think ?.

Comment: @Felix Well no, since $x^2/x^2=1$ almost everywhere.  And the value at $0$ can be taken as $1$.  Or are you asking about Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way of arriving at the result.  We use the simple regularization of the Dirac Delta given by

$$\delta_\epsilon(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{2\epsilon}&,x\in[-\epsilon,\epsilon]\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

where $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\delta_\epsilon(x) \sim \delta(x)$ in the sense of distributions.  That is, for every smooth function with compact support (i.e., test function), we have

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta_\epsilon(x)\,dx=f(0)$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1 x^2\delta(x^3)\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{-1}^1 x^2 \delta_\epsilon(x^3)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{-\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}}^\sqrt[3]{{\epsilon}}x^2\left(\frac1{2\epsilon}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac13
\end{align}$$

as expected!

---

Just to remark, the regularization we used herein in not unique.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine. Indeed you should perform the substitution $y=x^3$. With that you obtain
$$\int_{-1}^1\!dx\,x^2\delta(x^3) = \frac{1}{3}\int_{-1}^1\,dy\,\delta(y). \tag{1}$$
Now it is the defining property of the delta-distribution that 
$$\int\!dy\,f(y) \delta(y) =f(0).$$

Using for $f(y)$ the indicator function on $[-1,1]$, you obtain the result
$$\int_{-1}^1\!dx\,x^2\delta(x^3) = \frac{1}{3}\int_{-1}^1\,dy\,\delta(y) = \frac13.$$

Comment: shouldn't it be 0 if you directly apply the sifting property?

Comment: Sifting property of the delta function right?

Comment: @Goldname: if you refer to [this property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Translation), I do not understand how you can apply it directly?

Comment: @Fabian I'd guess the confusion is coming from what $\delta(x^3)$ means here.  If you mean the literal mapping $x \to \delta(x^3)$, then this function is identically 0.

Comment: I think you're right, I thought you could apply it directly, since at x = 0, delta is at the spike so I thought you could simply jump to 0^2.